# admin-on-rest: remove a textbox field passes in post data array to backend if other textbox value empty

Tags: admin-on-rest

I couldn't find way to prevent a textbox field passes to backend back based on other textbox value.

Example: If we have two fields such as checkbox and email. Suppose 
* If the checkbox is checked, then email fields should pass in post data array.
* If the checkbox is not checked, then email fields should not pass in post data array.

Note: The email field must be displaying always whether checkbox is passed or not.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by validation the form, https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/CreateEdit.html#validation

Require the email if the checkbox is active.

Another solution it to use a restClient/dataProvider middleware, but that's more advanced.